# swagger-codegen-cli: how to pass additional-properties

Tags: swagger-codegen

[swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) is used in the "official"
https://editor.swagger.io/ -
https://editor-next.swagger.io/ pages to convert .json or .yaml of swagger APIs to e.g. client code.

`java -jar ./swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l python` provides information on the available options, e.g.

```
projectName
    python project name in setup.py (e.g. petstore-api).
```

My question is how to set the option from the cli... [obviously directly as an option seems not working](https://groups.google.com/g/swagger-swaggersocket/c/6fYydLWwDeM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swagger Codegen CLI accepts those options as `-D{optionName}={optionValue}`.

For example (line breaks added for readability):

```
java -jar ./swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate
     -i myapi.yaml
     -l python
     -o ./python-sdk
     -DprojectName=MyApi
```

Another approach is to use the [`config.json` file](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#customizing-the-generator).